# Reshaping Keras layers

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have an input image 416x416. How can I create an output of 4 x 10, where 4 is number of columns and 10 the number of rows?

My label data is 2D array with 4 columns and 10 rows.

I know about the `reshape()` method but it requires that the resulted shape has same number of elements as the input.

With 416 x 416 input size and max pools layers I can get max `13 x 13` output.

Is there a way to achieve `4x10` output without loss of data?

My input label data looks like for example like

```
[[  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [116  16 128  51]
 [132  16 149  52]
 [ 68  31  77  88]
 [ 79  34  96  92]
 [126  37 147 112]
 [100  41 126 116]]
```

Which indicates there are  6 objects on my images that i want to detect, first value is xmin, second ymin , third xmax, fourth ymax.

The last layer of my networks looks like

```
(None, 13, 13, 1024)
```

Comment: The output of convolutions are usually 4-rank tensors in the format `(batch_size, height, width, kernels)`. I can see height and width are 13, but how many kernels do you have? Is 4 your `batch_size`, or do you want to transform a single sample in 4 different ones?

Comment: oh sorry, the output is 13 x 13 x 1024. The labels are in shape 4x 10 , each collumns represent one bounding box. So i detect up to 10 boxes. my batch size for training is 5.

Comment: You have `13 * 13 * 1024 = 173056` numbers to reshape into `4 * 10 = 40`. I'd say reshaping this is impossible without loss of data. What are you trying to do? Can you give us an example of how your label data look like?

Comment: i will uptade m queston for example of my label data

Comment: So you want to regress the values `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`? What were you thinking on trying after the reshape?

Comment: No, the input should stay as it is. However the shape output of my conv net should be matching the input/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168116/discussion-between-ldavid-and-darlyn).

Answer (score 10):

First flatten the `(None, 13, 13, 1024)` layer

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

it will give `13*13*1024=173056`

1 dimensional tensor

Then add a dense layer

`model.add(Dense(4*10))` it will output to 40

this will transform your 3D shape to 1D

then simply resize to your needs

`model.add(Reshape(4,10))`

This will work but will absolutely destroy the spatial nature of your data

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way to conform your predictions shape with the desired output is the solution proposed by @Darlyn. Assuming the network you have so far was declared (that outputs tensors of shape `(13, 13, 1024)`) as this:

```py
x = Input(shape=(416, 416, 3))
y = Conv2D(32, activation='relu')(x)
...
y = Conv2D(1024, activation='relu')(y)
```

You just need to add a regression layer that will try to predict the boxes, and then reshape these to `(10, 4)`:

```py
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Reshape

samples = 1
boxes = 10

y = Flatten(name='flatten')(model.outputs)
y = Dense(boxes * 4, activation='relu')(y)
y = Reshape((boxes, 4), name='predictions')(y)
model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=y)

x_train = np.random.randn(samples, 416, 416, 3)

p = model.predict(x_train)
print(p.shape)
```

> (1, 10, 4)

This works, but I'm not entire secure that directly regressing these values will produce good results. I usually see object-detection models using attention, region or saliency to determine the position of objects. There are a couple of object-detection keras implementations you could try:

#### [keras-rcnn](https://github.com/broadinstitute/keras-rcnn)

```py
classes = ["dog", "cat", "hooman"]

backbone = keras_rcnn.models.backbone.VGG16
model = keras_rcnn.models.RCNN((416, 416, 3), classes, backbone)
boxes, predictions = model.predict(x)
```

#### [keras-retinanet](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet)

```py
from keras_retinanet.models.resnet import resnet_retinanet

x = Input(shape=(416, 416, 3))
model = resnet_retinanet(len(classes), inputs=x)
_, _, boxes, _ = model.predict_on_batch(inputs)
```